# Can I choose between integrated and dedicated graphics?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, intel, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I have a system with an Intel Pentium G4600 and a AMD Radeon RX 560 that I'd like to install Ubuntu on. Is there a way to make Ubuntu ignore the AMD GPU and only use Intel graphics? I don't intend to game in Ubuntu and I don't want the system to use the GPU at all.

Comment: If that option is available you may disable the discrete graphics at UEFI settings.

Comment: True I didn't think of that! I'll check.

Comment: You can blacklist the AMD driver modules in Ubuntu. Will be easier than switching BIOS options all the time, if you're dual booting.

Comment: No that's alright. I don't intend to dual boot. But it's good to know that the blacklist option exists. Could you provide an answer pertaining to it?

Comment: I could set "primary graphics adapter from PCIe to integrated" in the UEFI. Does that mean that Ubuntu will not detect the graphics card upon install and will not install drivers for it? That would be good.